# Unable to run heroku after installing toolbelt

Tags: heroku, heroku-toolbelt

When i type heroku login i get this in the console

```
 Sumant Bagade@Specter MINGW32 ~/Desktop
$ heroku login
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies...
 !    Get https://cli-assets.heroku.com/node/v5.7.0/win-x86/node.exe: dial tcp: lookup cli-assets.heroku.com: getaddrinfow: No such host is known.
 done
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
 !

 !    exec: "C:\\Users\\Sumant Bagade\\AppData\\Local\\heroku\\node-v5.7.0-windows-x86\\bin\\node.exe": file does not exist
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
 !    Error installing package.
 !
 !    Try running again with GODE_DEBUG=info to see more output.
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies...
 !    Get https://cli-assets.heroku.com/node/v5.7.0/win-x86/node.exe: dial tcp: lookup cli-assets.heroku.com: getaddrinfow: No such host is known.
 done
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins...
 !

 !    exec: "C:\\Users\\Sumant Bagade\\AppData\\Local\\heroku\\node-v5.7.0-windows-x86\\bin\\node.exe": file does not exist
heroku-cli: Installing core plugins (retrying)...
 !    Error installing package.
 !
 !    Try running again with GODE_DEBUG=info to see more output.
heroku-cli: Adding dependencies...
 !    Get https://cli-assets.heroku.com/node/v5.7.0/win-x86/node.exe: dial tcp: lookup cli-assets.heroku.com: getaddrinfow: No such host is known.
 done
```

System is Window 8.1 64 bit.
Tried `npm cache clean` but didnt work. I am trying to deploy Node.js app on heroku

Comment: it's either the DNS isn't configured on your machine right or you don't have your proxy configured right

Comment: When i run heroku create its giving this error $ heroku create telecheck
Creating telecheck... !!!
 !    ENOTFOUND: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.heroku.com api.heroku.com:443
 !   Error in heroku-apps:
 !   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND api.rollbar.com api.rollbar.com:443
 !   See C:\Users\Sumant Bagade\AppData\Local\heroku\error.log for more info.